# How can I change a working python program so that it runs as python flask program

Tags: python, flask, expert-system

I have a python program, an expert system, it runs ok as a purely python program. but I now want to run it as a python flask program so that it can appear as on a browser and maybe be integrated as a whatsapp or sms chatbot.
the change from just python to make the code into sort of a chatbot is what I am looking for.

```
  # from pyknow import *
from experta import *
from flask import Flask
# import os
app = Flask(__name__)



# print(os.getcwd())
diseases_list = []
diseases_symptoms = []
symptom_map = {}
d_desc_map = {}
d_treatment_map = {}



def preprocess():
    global diseases_list,diseases_symptoms,symptom_map,d_desc_map,d_treatment_map
    diseases = open("diseases.txt")
    diseases_t = diseases.read()
    diseases_list = diseases_t.split("\n")
    diseases.close()
    for disease in diseases_list:
        #symptoms=os.path.dirname("symptoms/"+ disease + ".txt")
        disease_s_file = open("Dsymptoms/"+ disease + ".txt") 
        disease_s_data = disease_s_file.read()
        s_list = disease_s_data.split("\n")
        diseases_symptoms.append(s_list)
        symptom_map[str(s_list)] = disease
        disease_s_file.close()
        disease_s_file = open("Ddescriptions/" + disease + ".txt")
        disease_s_data = disease_s_file.read()
        d_desc_map[disease] = disease_s_data
        disease_s_file.close()
        disease_s_file = open("Dtreatments/" + disease + ".txt")
        disease_s_data = disease_s_file.read()
        d_treatment_map[disease] = disease_s_data
        disease_s_file.close()
    

def identify_disease(*arguments):
    symptom_list = []
    for symptom in arguments:
        symptom_list.append(symptom)
    # Handle key error
    return symptom_map[str(symptom_list)]

def get_details(disease):
    return d_desc_map[disease]

def get_treatments(disease):
    return d_treatment_map[disease]

def if_not_matched(disease):
        print("")
        id_disease = disease
        disease_details = get_details(id_disease)
        treatments = get_treatments(id_disease)
        print("")
        print("The most probable disease that you have is %s\n" %(id_disease))
        print("A short description of the disease is given below :\n")
        print(disease_details+"\n")
        print("The common nutritional treatments recommended by doctors, nurses and nutrionists are \n")
        print(treatments+"\n")
        

def identify_disease(*arguments):
    symptom_list = []
    for symptom in arguments:
        symptom_list.append(symptom)
    # Handle key error
    return symptom_map[str(symptom_list)]

def get_details(disease):
    return d_desc_map[disease]

def get_treatments(disease):
    return d_treatment_map[disease]

def if_not_matched(disease):
        print("")
        id_disease = disease
        disease_details = get_details(id_disease)
        treatments = get_treatments(id_disease)
        print("")
        print("The most probable disease that you have is %s\n" %(id_disease))
        print("A short description of the disease is given below :\n")
        print(disease_details+"\n")
        print("The common nutritional treatments recommended by doctors, nurses and nutrionists are: \n")
        print(treatments+"\n")

# @my_decorator is just a way of saying just_some_function = my_decorator(just_some_function)
#def identify_disease(bloated_stomach, thin_limbs,reddish hair, swollen face):
@app.route('/')
class Greetings(KnowledgeEngine):
    @DefFacts()
    def _initial_action(self):
        print("")
        print("Hi! I am Dr.Jephtah, I am here to help your child's health better.")
        print("Firstly I am are assuming that the child is under the age of 6 as this system works best for those childeren  ")
        print("For that you'll have to answer a few questions about your conditions")
        print("Do you feel any of the following symptoms:")
        print("")
        yield Fact(action="find_disease")

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(slight_hair=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_0(self):
        self.declare(Fact(slight_hair=input("slight hair: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(reddish_hair=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_1(self):
        self.declare(Fact(reddish_hair=input("reddish hair: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(hair_falling=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_2(self):
        self.declare(Fact(hair_falling=input("hair falling easily: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(abnormal_skin=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_3(self):
        self.declare(Fact(abnormal_skin=input("abnormal skin (eg skin shedding, lessions, skin ulcers): ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(swollen_face=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_4(self):
        self.declare(Fact(swollen_face=input("Swollen Face: ")))
    
    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(glazed_eyes=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_5(self):
        self.declare(Fact(glazed_eyes=input("glazed eyes: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(apathetic=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_6(self):
        self.declare(Fact(apathetic=input("child is apathetic: ")))
    
    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(smaller_muscles=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_7(self):
        self.declare(Fact(smaller_muscles=input("smaller muscles: ")))
    
    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(anaemic=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_8(self):
        self.declare(Fact(anaemic=input("anaemic (weak/tired): ")))
    
    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(diarrhoea=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_9(self):
        self.declare(Fact(diarrhoea=input("diarrhoea: ")))
    
    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(bloated_stomach=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_10(self):
        self.declare(Fact(bloated_stomach=input("bloated stomach: ")))
    
    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(thin_body=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_11(self):
        self.declare(Fact(thin_body=input("thin body: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(older_face=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_12(self):
        self.declare(Fact(older_face=input("Face looks older: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(cranky_child=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_13(self):
        self.declare(Fact(cranky_child=input("cranky child: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(wrinkled_skin=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_14(self):
        self.declare(Fact(wrinkled_skin=input("Wrinkled skin: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(little_fattie_tissue=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_15(self):
        self.declare(Fact(little_fattie_tissue=input("Liitle fattie tissue on hips and others: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(converse_stomach_rib_prominent=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_16(self):
        self.declare(Fact(converse_stomach_rib_prominent=input("converse stoamch rib prominent: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(chronic_infections=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_17(self):
        self.declare(Fact(chronic_infections=input("repeated chronic infections: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(skin_reddish_purging=W())),salience = 1)
    def symptom_18(self):
        self.declare(Fact(skin_reddish_purging=input("Skin reddish or purging: ")))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'), NOT(Fact(age=W())),salience = 20)
    def symptom_19(self):
        self.declare(Fact(age=input("Is age below 2 years: ")))     

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'),Fact(slight_hair="yes"),Fact(reddish_hair="yes"),Fact(hair_falling="yes"),Fact(abnormal_skin="yes"),Fact(swollen_face="yes"),Fact(glazed_eyes="yes"),Fact(apathetic="yes"),Fact(smaller_muscles="yes"),Fact(anaemic="yes"),Fact(diarrhoea="no"),Fact(bloated_stomach="yes"),Fact(thin_body="no"),Fact(older_face="no"),Fact(child_cranky="no"),Fact(wrinkled_skin="no"),Fact(little_fattie_tissue="no"),Fact(converse_stomach_rib_prominent="no"),Fact(chronic_infections="no"),Fact(skin_reddish_purging="no"),Fact(age="no"))
    def disease_0(self):
        self.declare(Fact(disease="Kwashiorkor"))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'),Fact(slight_hair="no"),Fact(reddish_hair="no"),Fact(hair_falling="no"),Fact(abnormal_skin="yes"),Fact(swollen_face="no"),Fact(glazed_eyes="no"),Fact(apathetic="no"),Fact(smaller_muscles="yes"),Fact(anaemic="yes"),Fact(diarrhoea="yes"),Fact(bloated_stomach="no"),Fact(thin_body="yes"),Fact(older_face="yes"),Fact(child_cranky="yes"),Fact(wrinkled_skin="yes"),Fact(little_fattie_tissue="yes"),Fact(converse_stomach_rib_prominent="yes"),Fact(chronic_infections="yes"),Fact(skin_reddish_purging="yes"),Fact(age="no"))
    def disease_1(self):
        self.declare(Fact(disease="Marasmus"))

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'),Fact(slight_hair="yes"),Fact(reddish_hair="yes"),Fact(hair_falling="yes"),Fact(abnormal_skin="yes"),Fact(swollen_face="yes"),Fact(glazed_eyes="yes"),Fact(apathetic="yes"),Fact(smaller_muscles="yes"),Fact(anaemic="yes"),Fact(diarrhoea="yes"),Fact(bloated_stomach="yes"),Fact(thin_body="yes"),Fact(older_face="yes"),Fact(child_cranky="yes"),Fact(wrinkled_skin="yes"),Fact(little_fattie_tissue="yes"),Fact(converse_stomach_rib_prominent="yes"),Fact(chronic_infections="yes"),Fact(skin_reddish_purging="yes"),Fact(age="no"))
    def disease_2(self):
        self.declare(Fact(disease="Marasmus-Kwashiorkor"))  

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'),Fact(slight_hair="yes"),Fact(reddish_hair="yes"),Fact(hair_falling="yes"),Fact(abnormal_skin="yes"),Fact(swollen_face="yes"),Fact(glazed_eyes="yes"),Fact(apathetic="yes"),Fact(smaller_muscles="yes"),Fact(anaemic="yes"),Fact(diarrhoea="no"),Fact(bloated_stomach="yes"),Fact(thin_body="no"),Fact(older_face="no"),Fact(child_cranky="no"),Fact(wrinkled_skin="no"),Fact(little_fattie_tissue="no"),Fact(converse_stomach_rib_prominent="no"),Fact(chronic_infections="no"),Fact(skin_reddish_purging="no"),Fact(age="yes"))
    def disease_3(self):
        self.declare(Fact(disease="Kwashiorkor_"))  

    
    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'),Fact(slight_hair="no"),Fact(reddish_hair="no"),Fact(hair_falling="no"),Fact(abnormal_skin="yes"),Fact(swollen_face="no"),Fact(glazed_eyes="no"),Fact(apathetic="no"),Fact(smaller_muscles="yes"),Fact(anaemic="yes"),Fact(diarrhoea="yes"),Fact(bloated_stomach="no"),Fact(thin_body="yes"),Fact(older_face="yes"),Fact(child_cranky="yes"),Fact(wrinkled_skin="yes"),Fact(little_fattie_tissue="yes"),Fact(converse_stomach_rib_prominent="yes"),Fact(chronic_infections="yes"),Fact(skin_reddish_purging="yes"),Fact(age="yes"))
    def disease_4(self):
        self.declare(Fact(disease="Marasmus_")) 


    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'),Fact(slight_hair="yes"),Fact(reddish_hair="yes"),Fact(hair_falling="yes"),Fact(abnormal_skin="yes"),Fact(swollen_face="yes"),Fact(glazed_eyes="yes"),Fact(apathetic="yes"),Fact(smaller_muscles="yes"),Fact(anaemic="yes"),Fact(diarrhoea="yes"),Fact(bloated_stomach="yes"),Fact(thin_body="yes"),Fact(older_face="yes"),Fact(child_cranky="yes"),Fact(wrinkled_skin="yes"),Fact(little_fattie_tissue="yes"),Fact(converse_stomach_rib_prominent="yes"),Fact(chronic_infections="yes"),Fact(skin_reddish_purging="yes"),Fact(age="yes"))
    def disease_5(self):
        self.declare(Fact(disease="Marasmus-Kwashiorkor_")) 


    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'),Fact(disease=MATCH.disease),salience = -998)
    def disease(self, disease):
        print("")
        id_disease = disease
        disease_details = get_details(id_disease)
        treatments = get_treatments(id_disease)
        print("")
        print("The most probable disease that you have is %s\n" %(id_disease))
        print("A short description of the disease is given below :\n")
        print(disease_details+"\n")
        print("The common treatments recommended by experts are: \n")
        print(treatments+"\n")

    @Rule(Fact(action='find_disease'),
        Fact(slight_hair=MATCH.slight_hair),
        Fact(reddish_hair=MATCH.reddish_hair),
        Fact(hair_falling=MATCH.hair_falling),
        Fact(abnormal_skin=MATCH.abnormal_skin),
        Fact(swollen_face=MATCH.swollen_face),
        Fact(glazed_eyes=MATCH.glazed_eyes),
        Fact(apathetic=MATCH.apathetic),
        Fact(smaller_muscles=MATCH.smaller_muscles),
        Fact(anaemic=MATCH.anaemic),
        Fact(diarrhoea=MATCH.diarrhoea),
        Fact(bloated_stomach=MATCH.bloated_stomach),
        Fact(thin_body=MATCH.thin_body),
        Fact(older_face=MATCH.older_face),
        Fact(cranky_child=MATCH.cranky_child),
        Fact(wrinkled_skin=MATCH.wrinkled_skin),
        Fact(little_fattie_tissue=MATCH.little_fattie_tissue),
        Fact(converse_stomach_rib_prominent=MATCH.converse_stomach_rib_prominent),
        Fact(chronic_infections=MATCH.chronic_infections),
        Fact(skin_reddish_purging=MATCH.skin_reddish_purging),
        Fact(age=MATCH.age),NOT(Fact(disease=MATCH.disease)),salience = -999)

        #   Fact(age=MATCH.age),
        
    def not_matched(self,slight_hair, reddish_hair, hair_falling, abnormal_skin, swollen_face, glazed_eyes, apathetic, smaller_muscles, anaemic ,diarrhoea ,bloated_stomach ,thin_body ,older_face, cranky_child ,wrinkled_skin ,little_fattie_tissue ,converse_stomach_rib_prominent ,chronic_infections, skin_reddish_purging, age):
        print("\nDid not find any disease that matches your exact symptoms")
        lis = [slight_hair, reddish_hair, hair_falling, abnormal_skin, swollen_face, glazed_eyes, apathetic, smaller_muscles,anaemic ,diarrhoea ,bloated_stomach ,thin_body ,older_face, wrinkled_skin, cranky_child, little_fattie_tissue, converse_stomach_rib_prominent, chronic_infections, skin_reddish_purging, age]
        max_count = 0
        max_disease = ""
        for key,val in symptom_map.items():
            count = 0
            temp_list = eval(key)
            for j in range(0,len(lis)):
                if(temp_list[j] == lis[j] and lis[j] == "yes"):
                    count = count + 1
            if count > max_count:
                max_count = count
                max_disease = val
        if_not_matched(max_disease)

        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    preprocess()
    engine = Greetings()
    while(1):
        engine.reset()  # Prepare the engine for the execution.
        engine.run()  # Run it!
        print("Would you like to diagnose some other symptoms?")
        if input() == "no":
            exit()
        #print(engine.facts)                                            
            




`
```

Comment: I've flagged this as requiring improvement due to low quality. You cannot just provide a block of code and expect somebody to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps in a Flask tutorial. Take a look at this [one](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)